# How to extract data from Behaviour Subject in Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

The objective behind using BehaviouSubject was to use a single API call and pass the same data to multiple components in the same route.
I am able to do that. I am not able to filter the received data

Heres a stackblitz fiddle that i have created

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtne5y

In one component, i am displaying the table, in the other, i need to extract some info out of it based on the individual object key values. Like how many todos are complete / incomplete.
Since I am required to use the async pipe everywhere in the template, performing operations like filter are not possible.
Is there a better way to implement this?

I need to keep the data extracted as reusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently using the `async` pipe. To get the desired result, you can use (or chain) another custom pipe with your data to fetch specific properties.

I've forked your stackblitz example and modified the code with the solution.
[Here's my working solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vct7or).

Essentially, all you need to do is use a custom pipe.

```
{{ todos$ | async | myCustomFilter }}
```

In my example (stackblitz), I'm doing:

```
    <p>
      No. of Completed Todos: {{ (todos$ | async | filterByCondition: {property: 'completed', value: true}).length }}
    </p>

    <p>
      No. of Incomplete Todos: {{ (todos$ | async | filterByCondition: {property: 'completed', value: false}).length }}
    </p>
```

#### Edit after your comments

There are two approaches to your desired result:
1) Use a custom pipe. You can parameterize the pipe the same as I've done or even create your own conditions and evaluate by passing a parameter to your pipe (as I've done in the example for the `args` property).

I.e

```html
    <div>{{$todos | async | filterTodo: 'byDate'}}</div>
```

Now, you can put the handler in your pipe filterTodo for this `byDate` value.

2) Use different observables for different data.

```js
  class MyComponent {
    todos$;
    completedTodos$;
    constructor() {
        this.todos$ = this.someService.getTodos(); // from behavior subject
        this.completedTodos$ = this.todos$.pipe(
            filter((item) => {
                // your filter code here
            })
        )
    }

  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to fetch data without using the async pipe?
and filter this result in the service itself so that the filtered output will be reusable.
Actually I wouldn't call it filtered because this is just extracting some data outof the response

Comment: Using `async` when fetching data from observables/behavior subjects is a preferred thing in the angular world. Is there a reason why you don't like chaining pipes to get the desired result? I believe that's the best and re-usable solution that includes the least amount of repeated code within your app.

Comment: If i use custom pipe in the template, I will have to create plenty of pipes as there are many conditions that need to be evaluated and fetch the value.

In angular 1.x I used to use $filter in the controller file and reuse. 

What would you suggest? is using pipes is the best way to go?

Comment: Also, the bigger objective is to minimize calculations and operations in the template and perform them in the typescript file (service/component ts)

Comment: @prawwe316 I've edited my answer. You can create the other observables/behavior subjects within the service too.

Comment: Thanks! The solution worked.
Now i am able to filter the observable (in the component).
I can probably use a subject to pass this filtered data to a different component. That way I can avoid redoing the filtering process in another component.  Right?

Comment: @prawwe316 You're absolutely right. You can create such observables/subjects within your services and just import them in your components for re-usability. A secret: NgRx does something similar for its state selectors ;)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help and advice

Answer (score 0):

So I've have worked on projects where when we create TODO's section, My approach would be when you subscribe to the URL to fetch the data, create a Redux Store 
(Here's [a link] https://medium.com/supercharges-mobile-product-guide/angular-redux-the-lesson-weve-learned-for-you-93bc94391958), which has an interface like

```js
interface ProductTodos {
    product: {title:string,iscompleted:boolean,id:string/number},
    todos?: any[]
}
```

When you fetch your Todos, you will dispatch an action like "PUSH" and every TODO will be an object of type product and will appended on to the todos array in the interface.

when you create an instance of the redux Store in the Component Class you will loop through the "todos" array and check for the id and isCompleted flag.

Based on this you can loop through each object and fill your tables based on their completed status.

Here is a link to my ReduxDemo in Angular 4, check it out https://github.com/nerdySingh/ReduxDemoAngular